# How to get an autowired bean from context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the various Spring bean contexts. For this purpose, I have a small application where I can create beans by

```
1. injection through configuration with XML configuration file
2. injection by `@Autowired` annotation and `application.properties`
```

Fetching the bean from the from the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` works as expected, however fetching from context after autowiring does not.

**The question is: how to fetch a bean from the context that has been `autowired`?**

This is the `application.properties` file:

```
com.example.demo.Demo.beanName=BEAN_PROPERTIES
```

Here's the bean definition:

```
public interface IDemo {
    public String getBeanName();
    public void setBeanName(String beanName);
}

@Component
@Qualifier("demoAnnotation")
public class Demo implements IDemo {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Demo.class);

    @Value("${com.example.demo.Demo.beanName:BEAN_NAME_DEFAULT}")
    private String beanName;

    @Override
    public String getBeanName() {
        return beanName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

}
```

The application has an autowired bean (*). However, when I fetch the bean from the context (**), the property is not set from the environment.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    // (*) Autowired injection.
    @Autowired
    private IDemo demoAnnotation; // <-- Logging beanName returns 'BEAN_PROPERTIES'

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run() {
        return args -> {

            // Fetch explicitly from context.
            ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoApplication.class);

            // (**) Logging getBeanName() from bean of context returns 'BEAN_NAME_DEFAULT'
            // demoAnnotation = (IDemo) ctx.getBean(Demo.class);

            // Logging autowired bean returns `BEAN_PROPERTIES`
            log.info(demoAnnotation.getBeanName());
        };
    }
}
```

This is the gradle build file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

UPDATE after comment:

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="demoXML" class="com.example.demo.Demo">
        <property name="beanName"><value>BEAN_XML</value></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(..)` is an entirely new `ApplicationContext`, completely unrelated to the one managed by Spring Boot, its `SpringApplication`.

Comment: @Savior Your reasoning is solid

Comment: You can inject Boot's `ApplicationContext` into your `@Bean` method `CommandLineRunner run(ApplicationContext ctx)` or as an `@Autowired` field itself.

Comment: The interesting thing is, that in the case using an XML configuration file, I can fetch the injected bean from a context created by `ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config.xml")`

Comment: Note that in all of these you don't really have separate contexts, just different styles of configuring the same context, and you can mix and match. (For a number of years it was common to see old application sections defined in XML imported from a JavaConfig class.)

Comment: What's in your `config.xml`? It won't be the same context, but maybe configured the same way.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- So its "One Application has one context"?

Comment: @Savior Added the `config.xml`.

Comment: Right, so you shouldn't be seeing `BEAN_PROPERTIES`. You should be seeing `BEAN_XML` printed if you load the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` explicitly.

Comment: @Savior That's exactly what's happening when I use the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.